# OpenVPN server won't accept a client connection based on IP aliasing

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, ufw

My OpenVPN server has multiple IP's (IP aliasing).
But OpenVPN clients aren't able to connect to the server through the secondary IP's. Only the primary IP works.

The secondary IP's could be pinged and used by other services on the server without any problem (like a webserver, MX and so on).

```
111.111.111.111 (primary server IP, works)
22.22.22.10 (secondary, doesn't work for client to connect, but works as outgoing IP for the client)
22.22.22.20 (secondary, doesn't work)
```

That's my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 22.22.22.10
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast 22.22.22.10

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 22.22.22.20
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast 22.22.22.20
```

`/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -j SNAT --to 22.22.22.10
COMMIT
```

Really no idea if I have used `iptables` for this too, that's too long ago. But I can't find any entries when running `iptables -L` (as far as I could understand iptables...)

How could this be done?

Thanks!

---

### Solution:

This finally works:

change local @ `server.conf`

`local 22.22.22.10`

Comment: Are you sure openvpn actually was told to accept datagrams on `22.22.22.10` via its `server` configuration directive?

Comment: As to iptables, be sure to also run `iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING` to see whether there's something of interest there.

Comment: Currently it's `server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0`. Changing it to `22.22.22.10 255.255.255.0` or `22.22.22.10 255.255.255.0` won't let the server start. And I don't have any entries @ iptables.

Comment: Oh... `local 22.22.22.10` did the trick! Thanks!